# How to move the window of another program to a specific x and coordinate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, window

I want my python script open a program and move the windows of the program to a specific coordinates. Is it possible with a windows monitor?

Here is an example:

- I start my program, input x = 150 and y = 200
- It starts `notepad.exe` and moves the window's top corner to x=150, y=200

Comment: No exactly sure what you mean by a "windows monitor". Something like this could probably be done in some OS-specific way — there's no generic way to do it in Python — but you haven't specified which OS you're using…

Comment: using Google "python move windows" I fould this [Find and move windows in Windows with ctypes and user32 in Python](https://gist.github.com/jerblack/2b294916bd46eac13da7d8da48fcf4ab) but I don't use Windows to check if it works.

Comment: see also [PyWinAuto](https://pywinauto.github.io/) and its [move_window](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.html?highlight=move#pywinauto.controls.hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper.move_window)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done quite simply with [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) which is installable using:

```
pip install pyautogui
```

You can then use something like:

```py
import subprocess
import time
import pyautogui

# Launch Notepad
subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe", ])
# Need a delay here to allow it to start so
time.sleep(0.5)
# Get the active window
np = pyautogui.getActiveWindow()
# Move it
np.moveTo(150, 200)
```

Of course you can modify the above to run something different &/or to take the position as arguments.

**Note** that the above code will run on any supported platform with the notable problem that the platforms other than windows will not support `"notepad.exe"` of course.