# Specify location co-ordinates to open an exe file using python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, subprocess, tkinter-canvas

I have created a Python tkinter application where in I have a button which when clicked opens the Calculator application (calci.exe).
However it opens in the default location of the screen. I want this calculator window to open inside the tkinter window that I have created.
Code to open the calci.exe:

```
def calci(): 
 subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\System32\calci.exe')


Calc=tk.Button(root,text='Calculator',command=calci)
Calc.place(x=6,y=6)
```

Is there any way I can open this calci.exe inside the Tkinter window?

Comment: I found a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844730/how-to-move-the-window-of-another-program-to-a-specific-x-and-coordinate) about this, do any of the comments help?

Comment: Tried it, but it did not help. I am not sure how to use move_window() in this scenario.

Comment: Well, PyWinAuto's `move_window` function lets you move any window to any screen coordinates. So, first look up how to get the screen coordinates of your Tkinter window, then use PyWinAuto's `move_window` to move the Calc window to the coordinates of the Tkinter window.